# SVN addon for VB6 does not work on Windows 8

Tags: svn, windows-8, vb6, tortoisesvn

I Just upgraded to Windows 8 from Windows 7.  The SVN addon works in VB6 when I do NOT run VB6 as administrator.  However, in order to load and compile my entire project I need to run VB6 as admin.  The problem is that when I run it as administrator, SVN fails with this error

[image]

I replaced some folder names in the screenshot but I have been using the same repository for over a year and it all worked perfectly with Windows 7.  Any information you may have on this error would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error was that VB6 on Windows 8 needed elevated permissions in order to run properly as administrator.  My repository is on a network drive and so VB6 did not have permission to access the repository.

To fix it, I added a registry value in the following location:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System/

Type: DWORD
Name: EnableLinkedConnections
Value: 1

Answer (score 1):

Run vb6 in a virtual environment (like vmware/vbox/..etc), and use some old windows that is known to work with vb6, like windows XP.

Edit: (based on the 1st comment)

The error appears to be from some source control software, consider replacing that software or looking for an alternative, the VB6 project itself should not be deeply affected by this move.

If you have done the move from windows 7 to windows 8 by doing an upgrade, try to do a clean install and then installing your software, sometimes a windows upgrade mess up allot of stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, a virtual environment is out of the question for me.  I am required to use Windows 8 and VB6 together.

Comment: That is correct.  SVN is source control software.  I cannot replace the software because it is required by all developers at my firm.  The software itself does work but the VB6 add-in for the software is failing.  VB6 is still working fine but I need the source control software add-in so I can manage what code is committed to my repository without having to access the file itself in Windows explorer.  I suspected it was my Windows 8 upgrade but my colleague did a fresh install of Windows 8 and the problem persists.